# Rails, remove flash message generated via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, flash-message

I have a flash message which is generated by an ajax response.
In my controller I have:

```
def destroy
  flash[:danger] = "Successfuly destroyed"
  format.js
end
```

which calls a destroy.js.erb file

```
$('#flash_messages').html("<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'layouts/flash_messages') %>");
```

that renders a partial which shows the flash messages. This partial looks like this:

```
#flash_messages
  -flash.each do |key, value|
    = content_tag(:div, value, class: "flash alert alert-#{key}")
```

I would like to use jquery to remove the flash message after 2 seconds. What I tried was:

```
$(".alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
  $(".alert").alert('close');
});
```

which, however, does not find the .alert class because it is generated after the page load. What is a workaround this problem :? Thank you!

Comment: You can write the Jquery code in the `destroy.js.erb` file. And then it will work. Jquery code you need to add after `$('#flash_messages').html("` line ofcourse. Did you try this?

Comment: That did the trick. Add it as an answer so that I can mark it as Accepted. Thank you!

Comment: there is some other way also to execute your code. Like executing the code when Ajax completes, from `success` callback. In that case, you don't need to put the JS inside the destroy.js.erb. But either way it will work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your JS was loaded into the page when the actual DOM, like the `<div class='alert'..` was not there. So, the binding didn't happen. 1 way to solve this, put the JS code inside the *destory.js.erb* file, after the file rendering logic. Another way is to execute JS code from the `success` callback of Ajax call for the particular element.